# How to even out an unordered list with variable height

Tags: css, list, unordered

I have an unordered list with variable height:

```
    <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
    <li style=" float:left"><div style="width:200px;">[divcontent]</div></li>
    <li style=" float:left"><div style="width:200px;">[divcontent]</div></li>
    etc
    </ul>
```

These div's contain text of variable length and as a consequence the height varies. This results in an unruly display when they have a border of a colored background. Even worse, when they wrap around to the next line they don't wrap to the left side but tend to stick behind some longer div in the middle.

All heights on a row should become the height of the highest item on that row. So if the highest item on row 1 is 100px all items (li's) on that row should become 100 high. If on the next row the highest item is 150px all items should get that height.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `Flexbox`, as you can see all items in one row will have the same height as tallest item from that row.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
 <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
  <li><div style="width:200px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis quod illum deleniti, cum modi ipsa vitae. Eos, tempore vero porro sapiente facilis? Asperiores ullam, adipisci minima quisquam, hic pariatur nam.</div></li>
  <li><div style="width:150px;">[divcontent]</div></li>
   <li><div style="width:100px;">[divcontent]</div></li>
  <li><div style="width:300px;">[divcontent]</div></li>
   <li><div style="width:200px;">[divcontent]</div></li>
  <li><div style="width:100px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero, porro.</div></li>
</ul>
```